# How to debug dynamically defined functions in Python?

Tags: python, debugging, dynamic

Is there a way to debug a function that is defined dynamically in run time?

Or at least is there an easy way to find out where this function is produced?

*Update to give more detail:*

I used `inspect` module:

```
ipdb> inspect.getmodule(im.get_thumbnail_url)
Out[0]: <module 'django.utils.functional' from 'C:\java\python\Python25\Lib\site
-packages\django\utils\functional.pyc'>
ipdb> inspect.getsource(im.get_thumbnail_url)
Out[0]: '    def _curried(*moreargs, **morekwargs):\n        return _curried_fun
c(*(args+moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))\n'
```

Here `inspect` shows that the `get_thumbnail_url` method of `photos.models.Image` class of pinax is produced by `django.utils.functional.curry._curried` function. But it still doesn't show where the method is produced, namely where is `_curried` function called. This information is necessary to find out how `get_thumbnail_url` is implemented.

I can put `pdb` inside `_curried` function, but then it breaks lots of times there because this is a very frequently used function call. I need to have some distinguishing feature to use breakpoint condition.

*Update about solution:*

Thanks for all suggestions. I found out the solution. Let me explain how I found it. Maybe it will help other people:

First, I searched for 'get_thumbnail_url' term in pinax source code. No result.
Second, I searched for 'thumbnail' term in pinax source code. No useful result.
Lastly, I searched for 'curry' term in pinax source code. The following was one of several results:

```
def add_accessor_methods(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for size in PhotoSizeCache().sizes.keys():
        setattr(self, 'get_%s_size' % size,
                curry(self._get_SIZE_size, size=size))
        setattr(self, 'get_%s_photosize' % size,
                curry(self._get_SIZE_photosize, size=size))
        setattr(self, 'get_%s_url' % size,
                curry(self._get_SIZE_url, size=size))
        setattr(self, 'get_%s_filename' % size,
                curry(self._get_SIZE_filename, size=size))
```

`get_thumbnail_url` method is produced by this call: `curry(self._get_SIZE_url, size=size))`.

But of course this is not a general solution method. If you can share alternative ways to find out where a dynamically defined function is actually produced, this would be of great use.

**Edit:**

The best [general solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008496/how-to-debug-dynamically-defined-functions-in-python/2009758#2009758) is written below by Jason Orendorff.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dynamically defined function"? Is this a `lambda` function or one generated by `exec("def foo():return bar")` or something similar?

Comment: Specifically, the function that I try to introspect now is a curried function. I don't think it is a lambda function nor one generated by exec. I don't know how it is defined exactly because I don't know where it is produced. But I guess the author used some kind of dispatching.

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: @Richo, if he could do that, he wouldn't be asking how to find the function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a function `f`, in CPython you can print `f.func_code.co_filename` and `f.func_code.co_firstlineno` to get the file and first line number. This will not help if the function was created using `eval` or `exec`.

Tracebacks contain file and line information too.

If you [`import dis`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) you can use `dis.dis(f)` to see the CPython bytecodes; this might not be useful, but it might show some strings that help you find your way to the right place.

Another thing to look at is [PDB](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html), the Python text-mode debugger. After an exception, `import pdb; pdb.pm()` launches PDB. It's primitive, but useful; type `help` for a list of commands. `where` shows the stack.

**EDIT:** You mention this is a curried function. If it was created using `functools.partial`, then it has a `.func` attribute that refers to the underlying function.

**EDIT 2:** The general way would be to set a breakpoint on `im.get_thumbnail_url` and then immediately call it. Your breakpoint should hit right away. Then step until you reach the code you're interested in.

Since the curried function was, in this case, produced by code like:

```
def curry(_curried_func,  *args,  **kwargs):
    def _curried(*moreargs, **morekwargs):
        return _curried_func(*(args+moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))
    return _curried
```

another approach is to examine `f.func_closure`, like this:

```
>>> f
<function _curried at 0xb77d64fc>
>>> f.func_closure
(<cell at 0xb77eb44c: tuple object at 0xb77dfa0c>, <cell at 0xb77eb5e4: dict object at 0xb77d93e4>, <cell at 0xb77eb5cc: function object at 0xb77d1d84>)
```

The function closes on three variables: a tuple, a dict, and a function. Obviously the function is the one we're interested in (but fyi these three cells correspond to the variables `args`, `kwargs`, and `_curried_func` that are defined in the enclosing function `curry` but used by the closure `_curried`).

```
>>> f.func_closure[2].cell_contents
<function say at 0xb77d1d84>
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getsource(_)
'def say(x):\n    print x\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but you can get a function to print out the source file and line number it was defined in using the inspect module:

```
import inspect
f = lambda: inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_filename + ':' + \
  str(inspect.currentframe().f_lineno);
print f()
```

It prints:

```
script.py:2
```